# Prove that the set consists of (un)bounded sequences

Tags: general-topology

I don't understand the highlighted statement, how can one prove this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $a$  is bounded then $|a_i|<M$ for all $i$ therefore every point in $(a_{i-1},a_{i+1})$ is bounded by $M+1$

Thus every sequences in the Cartesian product is bounded.

Similarly you can argue for the unbounded case .